# How to implement a formula pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types, root-framework

## Disclaimer

Firstly, I am very sorry for the title of this question. It was not easy for me to formulate what I want in short. If you know how to change it - please, advice.

## Problem description

### Preliminaries

I have a huge amount of structured data which is a tree (ROOT TTree object) of variables of *different* types. Elementary unit of that data is so called *entry* or *event*. So different entries contain *different values of the same variables*. The latter is not the most clear statement. Think of that tree in the following way: it is like a matrix where rows are entry numbers (0, 1, 2, ... ) and columns are variable names (*energy*, *momentum*, *theta*, ...).

### What we need

We need to perform a global selection on those events. I.e. we have to decide which events are for the further analysis and which are not. In order to reach this we have developed several algorithms which we call *selectors*. These selectors use different parameters of an event (variables) to decide if it passed or not. The procedure or algorithm behind the current selector we will call *Formula* and variables that this algorithm uses inside - *variables*.

We are doing our selection event by event. I.e. each event goes through each selector and if it fails (not passed) for some of them (selectors) the next event take a turn.

### Programming issues

Each selector is represented by a class derived from an abstract base class:

```
 class Selector:
 {
     protected :
         bool status;

     public :
         virtual bool Formula() = 0;//must be overridden for a specific Selector
 };
```

You see that pure function `Formula` takes no argument. It is reasonable because we do not know what arguments it should take until we know what selector we use. So information of variables could be stored in class data members. For example, in this way

```
class SpecificSelector : public Selector
{
    private :
        std::vector<?> variables;//or std::array

    public :
        void AddVariable ( /*pointer to a variable*/ ) { variables.push_back( &variable ); }
        bool Formula() { return ( *variables[0] + *variables[1] ) > 1 ? true : false; }
};
```

But wait. Variables could be any (reasonable) type. So we have to know what is what. May be so

```
class SpecificSelector : public Selector
{
    private :
        std::vector<int* > intVariables;//or std::array
        std::vector<float* > floatVariables;
    public :
        void AddIntVariable ( /*pointer to a variable*/ ) { intVariables.push_back( &variable ); }
        void AddFloatVariable ( /*pointer to a variable*/ ) { floatVariables.push_back( &variable ); }
        bool Formula() { return ( *intVariables[0] + *intVariables[1] ) > 1 ? true : false; }
};
```

But types could be more exotic. Arrays, for example.

Maybe it is a place for templates here? What is a way to reach the desired? How to implement such kind of `Formula` member function.

We think the problem is very common despite we presented it in such specific way.

Comment: _[SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)_ maybe?

Comment: Also there are things like `boost::spirit`. Could be helpful to implement DSLs.

Comment: Why not havr formulas consume rows?  Are the types runtime or compiletime determined?  Is the set of types your variables can be enumerable or not?

Comment: Not sure what's the best for you, so just some keywords: Did you consider working with `TTree::MakeClass`? I usually generate a base class in the build process with `MakeClass` and then derive from it, and have thus all branches declared and initialised. Alternatively, would a `TTreeFormula` work for you or `TEntryList`?
And of cause a more modern framework is the `TDataFrame`.

Comment: Have you considered using a string to express the formula, in the same way as done in `TTree::Draw`, `TTree::GetEntries` etc.? If you have all the required variables in your input tree, i.e. no time-consuming calculation needed on-the-fly, then I'd suggest this approach (+index the chain for faster access, e.g. [indexed_chain.py](https://github.com/gerbaudo/root_utils/blob/master/indexed_chain.py))

Comment: If you derive from class built by `MakeClass` isn't the fact that you make many copies of each branch, variable each time you create new class? I have very big tree.

Comment: @Yakk, could you, please, explain what did you mean under 'formulas consume rows'? And, answering your questions, types are compile-time determined. And can be enumerated.

Comment: Rows could be tuples.  Formulas functions on tuples.  Tuple elements can be variants.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just have your cuts defined outside the event loop, you could do something like this.
I'm assuming you are using at least `c++11`. `root6` has required it for ages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

// Function that checks if calls to all tuple elements are true
template <typename T, size_t I = 0>
std::enable_if_t<(I+1 < std::tuple_size<T>::value),bool>
apply_cuts(T& cuts) { // base case
  if (!std::get<I>(cuts)()) return false;
  return apply_cuts<T,I+1>(cuts);
}
template <typename T, size_t I = 0>
std::enable_if_t<(I+1 == std::tuple_size<T>::value),bool>
apply_cuts(T& cuts) { // last cut
  return std::get<I>(cuts)();
}
template <typename T, size_t I = 0>
std::enable_if_t<(std::tuple_size<T>::value == 0),bool>
apply_cuts(T&) { // no cuts
  return true;
}

int main() {

  // Open TFile
  // Get TTree
  // . . .

  unsigned event;
  double position;
  int id;
  std::vector<int> substructure;

  // Set Branch Addresses
  // . . .

  // Instead of doing all that stuff with selectors that
  // have pointers to the variables
  // just capture variables by reference with lambda functions
  auto cuts = std::make_tuple(
    [&]{ return position > 2; },
    [&]{ return id > 0; },
    [&]{ return substructure.size() >= 3; }
  );

  // Event loop
  // I'm emulating this part by hand below
  // You would have something like this instead
  /*
  for (Long64_t i=0; i<num_events; ++i) {
    tree->GetEntry(i);
    if (!apply_cuts(cuts)) continue;

    // Do something with selected events
    // . . .
  }
  */

  // Test events

  // Event 1
  event = 1;
  position = 65.65;
  id = 5;
  substructure = { 1,2,3,4 };

  std::cout << "Event " << event << ": "
            << (apply_cuts(cuts) ? "passed" : "rejected") << std::endl;

  // Event 2
  event = 2;
  position = 2.35;
  id = -1;
  substructure = { 1,2 };

  std::cout << "Event " << event << ": "
            << (apply_cuts(cuts) ? "passed" : "rejected") << std::endl;

}
```

[[Wandbox] demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7jNdtW5jykuDyf6q)

`std::enable_if_t<...>` is syntactic sugar from `c++14`. In `c++11` you need to type `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` instead.

In `c++17` you could write `apply_cuts` like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool apply_cuts(T& cuts) {
  return std::apply([](auto&... x){ return (x() && ...); }, cuts);
}
```

Comment: I love the C++ syntax and concepts because of their transparency and lucidness.

Comment: So, is this the kind of answer you were looking for?

Comment: Firstly, that was a sarcasm. Secondly, I do not know because I am trying to understand your answer now.